# Laravel Self Relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, query-builder, relationships

Well, i have this table in my Database:

```
CREATE TABLE categories(
id INT,
name VARCHAR,
id_parent INT,
CONSTRAINT fk_categories FOREIGN KEY(id_parent) REFERENCES categories(id)
);
```

In Laravel Category model, I have this:

```
class Category extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = "categories";

    public function parentCategory(){
        return $this->belongsTo("Category","id_parent");
    }

    public function subCategories(){
        return $this->hasMany("Category","id_parent");
    }
}
```

Also I have this data:

```
id        name          id_parent
1         category_1    NULL
2         category_2    NULL
3         category_3    1
4         category_4    1
5         category_5    2
```

When I call in the controller:

```
count(Category::with("subCategories")->get()); The count returns 5.
```

And when I call  in the controller:

```
count(Category::has("subCategories")->get()); The count returns 0.
```

All this is bad, because I want only the categories that parent_id = NULL, that will return to the count 3.

If I use `count(Category::where("id_parent","!=","NULL")` the result is 3 (it's OK), but I want to get this result by using HAS or WITH function.

So, how can I do this without using "where" function?

Sorry about my English.

Comment: How many tables and models you have here?  I see `categories` table, some other table ('category` ?) and at least 2 models `Category` and `PropertyCategory` and you ask about self relationship. I think I don't understand your structure and what you want to achieve

Comment: Oh!! sorry, I've changed all mistakes. The model is Category and the table who is referencing is categories.
I put it as you see because laravel says that you must call your tables in plural and his model in singular.

Comment: You should consider using https://github.com/etrepat/baum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your errors in your code are copy-paste errors (in one places you have `parent_id` and in others `id_parent` you cannot do this using `has`.

It seems a bug for me because wrong query is being executed. I've created [Github issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6190)  for that, I've seen at least other similar issue.

Comment: I've changed it another time. Even as now, I cannot use has??
What should I change?

Comment: @Developer I'm not expert but it seems that if relationship is for same table, when using `has` wrong query is being created so you will always get 0 records. Look at github issue I've created to see exact problem